# How to `'load-file'` the associated file for the current buffer?

Tags: emacs

> How to `'load-file'` the associated file for the current buffer?

After editing `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, I want to reload it, so I issue the command `M-x load-file`.

The problem is however, that sometimes the prompt starts in a directory far away from `~/.emacs.d` like `C:/Users/...`.

Why does this starting place change, and how do I load the associated file for the current buffer fast?

Comment: Before you call `M-x load-file`, is the currently-selected window the one with the buffer visiting your `init.el` file? Also, can you confirm that your truncated `C:/Users/...` path *isn't* the same thing as `~/.emacs.d`? Because on Windows the latter would presumably live somewhere in that unspecified `...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the currently-selected window is displaying the buffer which is visiting the file you wish to load, then you *should* be able to use:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `load-file` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

`load-file` will load the visited file if you do not type a file name at the prompt.

Note that you do *not* need to delete the default value (which is a directory path); simply type `RET`.

This is the case even if you have done something to change the buffer's `default-directory` (in which case the default value at the prompt may not actually be the parent directory of the visited file). When you just type `RET` Emacs uses the absolute path of `buffer-file-name`, making `default-directory` inconsequential.

Answer (score 1):

`load-file` uses the current buffer's value of `default-directory` as the default directory. And if the current buffer is visiting a file, the directory containing that file serves as the default.

You can set it by:

```
(setq-local default-directory "~/.emacs.d/")
```

and set it for specified mode (if necessary):

```
(setq-mode-local jde-mode default-directory "~/.emacs.d/")
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. But I hoped there was some easy key combination like RET RET to load the associated file with the current buffer...